# How to deploy a Glassfish application on CloudBees

Tags: deployment, web, glassfish, cloudbees

I'm trying to deploy my Web application running on *Glassfish* on *Cloudbees*.

Unfortunately I didn't find any documentation or tutorial.
I'll be very thankful if anybody can explain me the best way to do this. I'm lost...
Thank you!
(PS: I'm working on *Netbeans*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application is working, actually I had to create an application using *JavaEE6* in *configuration* (it's a **jboss** server in reality).

I configured the *persistence.xml* and added a *cloudbees-web.xml*.
I also deleted some *hibernate and mysql jar(s)* and it has worked!

I hope that can help others cloudbees developers!

Answer (score 0):

To deploy, you need to right-click on the project in the NetBeans project list and click "Deploy". Obviously you need to ensure that the properties for the project are pointing to the correct deployment location and directory.

Comment: Thank you!
Actually my app works perfectly I can deploy it and run it, but I just want to know step to use cloudbees.

Answer (score 0):

To get a glassfish container at runtime you'll need to setup your application to run he related [clickstack](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/glassfish3-clickstack/). You'll need the CloudBees SDK installed, and run this command :

```
bees app:deploy -a DOMAIN/APP_ID -t glassfish3  hello.war
```

Another option is to use cloudbees clickstart (see clickstart icon top left on cloudbees web toolbar) and select the glassfish one. Then commit your own code in the generated application skeleton, or change the generated jenkins job to point to your existing SCM

Please note this container is a community work in progress, doesn't provide all the features you can have on the tomcat6 or jboss7 runtimes. If your application isn't container dependent, those ones may be a better option then.

Comment: Thank you! Well I tried the first solution and it works but when I want to access the web page, I have the glassfish page "Your server is now running". How can I display my own views. Thank you!